# Executor services with standalone Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to run Hazelcast as standalone application and run executor service against it but getting this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Resolving class hazelcastexample.EchoTask is not allowed.
```

Here is my member class(standard example from Hazelcast)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig = new ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
    // clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addJar("/User/example/example.jar");
    clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addJar("/Users/.../workspaces/local/hazelcastexample/target/hazelcastexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    // clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass("example.ClassName");
    clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass("hazelcastexample.EchoTask");
    clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);
    clientConfig.setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig);
    HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    IExecutorService executor = hz.getExecutorService("executor");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Producing echo task: " + i);
        executor.execute(new EchoTask("" + i));
    }
    System.out.println("MasterMember finished!");
    executor.execute(new EchoTask("foo"));
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: The code snippet you have posted is not member's, its your client code. Do you have configuration code for member or actual configuration, possibly in an xml that you can share? Also, it would be helpful if you could point to the repo or class name from the examples.

Comment: Thanks, @wildnez for your response. I got it working with allowing UserCodeDeployment on hazelcast instance.
https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/clusters/deploying-code-on-member.html